# At which point array class is being created in java?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, polymorphism, equals

Today I tried to compare two arrays using `equals()`, it obviously failed, I started diggin' etc etc, and after some research I can't quite figure out: at which point in time the class for an array is being created? Cuz I know that `int [] a` leads to creation of an array class for integers. Who creates it? Why it was impossible to override `Object.equals()` so that it doesn't compare two objects and compares elements of arrays instead? Would be very grateful if someone could explain or provide a link, which would help to understand that.

Comment: You should use [`Arrays.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int[],%20int[])) to do that

Comment: "Why it was impossible to override Object.equals() so that it doesn't compare two objects and compares elements of arrays instead?" It wasn't impossible, it just wasn't done. Now we are stuck with these semantics so as not to break code relying on them.

Comment: @sharonbn i know it by now, that wasn't the question

Comment: Why do you think a class is created?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, of course a class is created. you can do `array.toString()` among other things

Comment: @RealSkeptic so it's just Oracle was lazy, right?

Comment: @LeonidBor well, it would be Sun who originally designed it. But no, they weren't necessarily lazy, they just didn't have the benefit of hindsight.

Comment: @sharonbn That doesn't mean that a class is created. That means that an object is created. And that this object has some features that allow it to be used the same way that any other object is used. But it seems the OP thinks that there is an actual source where you would be able to write your own methods or something.

Comment: The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7) dictates that `equals` is inherited from `Object`. Also related: [Why do arrays in Java not override equals()?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/239139/why-do-arrays-in-java-not-override-equals)

Comment: @RealSkeptic right, but you can access `int[].class`, `int[][].class` etc, and `array.getClass()`. So there is a class instance associated with the array, which is distinct from the element type's class (`Integer.TYPE`, in the case of `int`).

Comment: @AndyTurner an instance of `Class` is not the same as a class. It's merely an access point for reflection, etc. - even primitives have an associated `Class` instance!

Comment: @JornVernee thank you, that was really helpful and interesting. Some external library is mentioned there that works with array, where can I have a look at it?

Comment: @LeonidBor Do you mean [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) ? that is a part of the standard api.

Comment: @JornVernee ah, got it wrong first time I read the article. Ok, now all seems clear, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Array` doesn't override `equals()` of the Object class.
So it will not use the `equals()` method of the objects that it holds when `equals()` is invoked on an Array.

If you want to compare two arrays of integer, you can use  `Arrays.equals()` method. 
If it doesn't suit you, create your own method to compare two array of integers.

But overriding `equals()` of Array is not possible as the class is final and besides it seems rather a weird approach.

Comment: I do not want to override array class, I want to know why java developers (Oracle or whoever) didn't override `Object.equals()`

Comment: because it would have too side effects as all classes derive from it.

Comment: "all classes derive from it" No they don't.

Comment: @Andy Turner Can you detail please ? It interests me.

Comment: Why would anybody derive from array class created during runtime by jvm?

Comment: @davidxxx no classes derive from array classes. They are final.

Comment: @Andy Turner Ah...I expected to a big surprise.  In fact I said that all classes derive from Object, not Array. Leonid Bor has updated its initial comment. BTW I precised that **overriding equals() of Array is not possible as the class is final**